# Intuitive explanation of a Pascal's triangle result

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

We know that, in Pascal's triangle, the sum of all the elements of row $n$ is equal to $2^n$, i.e.:
$$\sum^n_{k=0} {n \choose k}=2^n. $$

Is there an intuitive explanation for why is this true?

Comment: There are lots of combinatorial proofs of this identity. I quite like the interpretation as the number of binary words of length $n$ (using $0$'s and $1$'s) and the terms on the LHS as the binary words with $k$ $1$'s.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Is it possible to have a reference with details on that?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find a good ref, but if you search "binary words" on this site you will find lots of nice examples where they are used (usually with some restrictions on their "grammar")

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Okay. From what I understood from your comment, you might be referring to interpretation explained in the first comment of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/546417). Are you not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An intuitive explanation which can easily be developed into a formal proof: the left hand side is the number of subsets of an $n$-element set which have $0$ elements or $1$ element or... or $n$ elements.  The right hand side is the total number of subsets.  These two quantities are clearly the same.

Comment: For completeness, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/546417) explains why $2^n$ corresponds to the total number of subsets. See also comments therein.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that $(p+q)^n$ expands using Pascal's triangle - the term with $r$ elements $p$ and $n-r$ elements $q$ is $$\binom nr p^rq^{n-r}$$

Now put $p=q=1$ and consider $2^n=(1+1)^n$