# Fraïsse Theorem in Bruno Poizat's "A course in model theory"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

In Bruno Poizat's "A course in model theory" book, I didn't understand the lemma used to prove the second part of the theorem stating that "$p$-equivalence classes are finite for $n$-tuples where $n$ is fixed". The part that I didn't understand was how the given formula $$C(n,p+1)\leq 2^{C(n+1,p)}$$ was deduced from the fact:

> In other words, the $(p+1)$-equivalence class of an $n$-tuple is determined by the set of all $p$-equivalence classes of $(n+1)$-tuples obtained by adding one element to it.

Comment: Can you give a page number?

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but surely this is explained by noting that if $C(n+1,p)$ is the number of $p$-equivalence classes of $(n+1)$-tuples, then the number of *sets* of such equivalence classes is $2^{C(n+1,p)}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange! On this site, you can use MathJax (similar to LaTeX) to display mathematical symbols. I've edited your post to add MathJax, improve formatting, and correct some typos.

Comment: Page number- 24

Comment: But how the number of such sets is 2^{C(n+1,p)}

Comment: @Charlie the number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements is $2^n$.

Comment: (A clarifying comment for this discussion.) The inequality in the question is $C(n,p+1)\leq 2^{C(n+1,p)}$; not $C(n+1,p)\leq 2^{C(n+1,p)}$.

Comment: @GabeConant Who suggested otherwise? :0)

Comment: @Alex Ok good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poizat says:

> Two $n$-tuples are $(p+1)$-equivalent if whenever I add an element on one side, I can respond with an element on the other side of such a type as to have $p$-equivalence.

So the situation boils down to this:

Suppose we have a set $X$ and, for any integers $p\geq 0$ and $n\geq 1$, we have an equivalence relation $\sim_{p,n}$ on $X^n$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:

1. For all $n\geq 1$, $\sim_{0,n}$ has finitely many classes.
2. For all $n\geq 1$, if $\bar{a},\bar{b}\in X^n$ then $\bar{a}\sim_{p+1,n}\bar{b}$ if and only if

   - for any $a'\in X$ there is a $b'\in X$ such that $\bar{a}a'\sim_{p,n+1}\bar{b}b'$, and
   - for any $b'\in X$ there is $a'\in X$ such that $\bar{a}a'\sim_{p,n+1}\bar{b}b'$.

Here $\bar{a}a'$ denotes the $(n+1)$-tuple in $X^{n+1}$ obtained by concatenating $a'$ on the end of $\bar{a}$ (and similarly for $\bar{b}b'$). Note that condition (2) is precisely transcribing Poizat's quote above.

Now, given $p\geq 0$ and $n\geq 1$, define $C(p,n)$ to be the cardinality of the set of $\sim_{p,n}$-classes on $X^n$. The goal is to show that $C(p,n)$ is finite for all $n$ and the proof proceeds by induction on $p$. The base case $p=0$ is precisely condition (1) above. So fix $p$ and assume $C(p,n)$ is finite for all $n$. The main claim is:

**Claim.** For all $n\geq 1$, $C(p+1,n)\leq 2^{C(p,n+1)}$.

**Proof.** Fix $n\geq 1$, and let $k=C(p,n+1)$.  We are going to show that the number of $\sim_{p+1,n}$-classes is at most $2^k$ by using condition (2) to exhibit an injective function from the set of all $\sim_{p+1,n}$-classes to the set of all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$.

Let $\bar{a}_1,\ldots,\bar{a}_k\in X^{n+1}$ be a full set of representatives for the equivalence relation $\sim_{p,n+1}$ (so *any* $(n+1)$-tuple in $X^{n+1}$ is equivalent to $\bar{a}_i$ for some $1\leq i\leq k$). Given an $n$-tuple $\bar{a}\in X^n$, define the set
$$
I_{\bar{a}}=\{1\leq i\leq n:\bar{a}_i\sim_{p,n+1}\bar{a}a'\text{ for some }a'\in X\}.
$$
(In other words, $I_{\bar{a}}$ is the set of indices $i$ such that $\bar{a}_i$ is $\sim_{p,n+1}$-equivalent to an $(n+1)$-tuple obtained by adding an element of $X$ to the end of $\bar{a}$.)

Now suppose we have two $n$-tuples $\bar{a},\bar{b}\in X^n$. Then condition (2) above exactly says:
$$
\bar{a}\sim_{p+1,n}\bar{b}\text{ if and only if }I_{\bar{a}}=I_{\bar{b}}.~(\ast)
$$
(If you're unsure of this then I encourage writing out the details.)

So let $S$ be the set of all $\sim_{p+1,n}$-classes, and let $P$ be the set of all subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. Then, by $(\ast)$, we have a well-defined injective function $f\colon S\to P$ such that, given a $\sim_{p+1,n}$-class $c\in P$, $f(c)$ is defined to be $I_{\bar{a}}$, where $\bar{a}$ is an arbitrary element of the class $c$. Since [$P$ has cardinality $2^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546414/what-is-the-proof-that-the-total-number-of-subsets-of-a-set-is-2n), we have $|S|\leq 2^k$, which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Look, I know that no. of subsets is 2^k, but I didn't get your proof.

Comment: Can you try to prove it in a different way?

Comment: I added more details. If you can isolate a specific part of the proof you don't get, then I can try to clarify further.

Comment: Now I get it. I actually didn't get the definition of "Ia" set in the previous one. Thanks a lot.