# Extend topological space by an isolated point and compatiblity with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $\Delta\not\in E$;
- $E_\Delta:=E\cup\{\Delta\}$;
- $\mathcal E_\Delta$ denote the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $E_\Delta$ containing $\mathcal E$; i.e. $$\mathcal E_\Delta=\mathcal E\cup\{B\cup\{\Delta\}:B\in\mathcal E\}.$$

If

- $(E,\tau)$ is a topological space;
- $\mathcal E$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(E)=\sigma(\tau)$ on $E$;
- $\tau_\Delta$ is the smallest topology on $E_\Delta$ containing $\tau$,

Then, can we show that

1. $\sigma(\tau_\Delta)=\mathcal E_\Delta$?
2. If $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ is continuous, then it is also continuous as a map into $E_\Delta$?
3. If $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $f(\Delta):=0$, then $f$ is continuous as a map on $E_\Delta$?

Comment: What have you tried? You now seem to have even an explicit formula for the new  sigma algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Proof of ${\cal E}_\Delta=\sigma(\tau_\Delta)$.

   Since ${\cal E}=\sigma(\tau)$ we know from from the answer to the related question   that
   $$
   {\cal E}_\Delta=\sigma(\tau)\cup\{B\cup\{\Delta\},B\in\sigma(\tau)\}
   $$
   holds. This means that the collection
   $$
   {\cal C}=\tau\cup\{B\cup\{\Delta\},B\in\tau\}
   $$
   generates the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal E}_\Delta\,.$

   The smallest topology on $E_\Delta$ containing $\tau$ is
   $$
   \tau_\Delta=\tau\cup\{E_\Delta\}\subseteq{\cal C}\,.
   $$
   Therefore,
   $$
   \sigma(\tau_\Delta)\subseteq\sigma({\cal C})={\cal E}_\Delta\,.
   $$
   To show ${\cal E}_\Delta\subseteq\sigma(\tau_\Delta)$ we take any $C\in{\cal C}\,.$
   This $C$ is of the form
   $$
   B\quad\text{ or }\quad B\cup\{\Delta\}\quad\text{ for some }B\in\tau\,.
   $$
   When $C=B$ then clearly $C\in\tau\subseteq\tau_\Delta\,.$
   When $C=B\cup\{\Delta\}$ then any $\sigma$-algebra in $E_\Delta$ that contains $C$ also contains its complement $E_\Delta\setminus C$.
   It is easy to see that this complement is
   is $E\setminus B$ and belongs to $\sigma(\tau)\,.$ Therefore, $E_\Delta\setminus C\in\sigma(\tau_\Delta)$ and also $C\in\sigma(\tau_\Delta)\,.$
2. If $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ is continuous then, for every $B\in\tau$ the preimage
   $x^{-1}(B)$ is open in $[0,\infty)\,.$ If $C\in\tau_\Delta\setminus\tau$ then
   $$
   C=B\cup\{\Delta\}\,,\quad\text{ for some }B\in\tau\,.
   $$
   Because $x$ takes only values in $E$ it is $x^{-1}(C)=x^{-1}(B)\in\tau\subseteq\tau_\Delta\,.$ In other words,
   $$
   x:[0,\infty)\to (E_\Delta,\tau_\Delta)
   $$
   is continuous.
3. The answer is no. Let $E=[0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)\,.$ This $f$ is continuous on $(E,\tau)\,.$ Since the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist it cannot be made continuous on $E_\Delta=[0,\infty]\,.$